# ListItem Mouse Enter Message Box

Tags: wpf, events, triggers, mouse, enter

I am using event triggers in my XAML, I have the following style set on a ListItem. What I want is to display the contents of the ListItem in a message box when the mouse enters a list item.

```
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">

            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
```

I am wondering if its possible to fire code behind when the mouse enters the listitem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="_listBoxItem_MouseEnter"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Hi Kent, Thank you that does help. However when I cast the sender to my custom object [Person p = sender as Person]; I get a null in the object "p". The class Person has a BitmapImage and a String holding the info to the image and this info is what I want to show in the messagebox. Any pointers?

Comment: Hi Anand. The sender will be the ListBoxItem. You can cast sender to ListBoxItem and then cast the DataContext of the ListBoxItem to your Person class.

Comment: Hi Kent, Thanks a lot, what I did was to override the ToString method in the Person class to return the necessary string. But your solution is much more better than overriding ToString. :-)